# MS access code to insert data into another table (validation rule error)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a user form that inserts data into "user" table and "organizer" table when I click a button, user data gets inserted with no problem, but it prompts me to enter the value (organization_name) again in a small dialogue box -which supposed to take from the text field and insert into organizer table- ,
then gives me an error saying "ms access set one row null due to validation rule violation"

NOTE: I didn't put any validation rule for the "organization_name" anywhere

```
Private Sub InsertSqlIntoOrgTable()
   Dim orgName As String, SqlOrgNameInsert As String

   orgName = txtOrgName.Value  'takes the value from text field
   SqlOrgNameInsert = "INSERT INTO ORGANIZER (ORG_NAME)     VALUES (" & orgName & ") "

   DoCmd.RunSQL SqlOrgNameInsert

End Sub
```

Comment: is the organizer name empty?

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be trying to insert into the field `organization_name` instead of `ORG_NAME`?

Comment: the organizer name field in not empty,i have programmed the form to not proceed and give massage if it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SqlOrgNameInsert = "INSERT INTO ORGANIZER (ORG_NAME) VALUES ('" & orgName & "') "
```

if the field name in table ORGANIZER is really ORG_NAME. Show us your complete table definition in case that this doesn't solve your problem. Because in your last question you posted:

```
sqlOrgInsertUsrId = "INSERT INTO ORGANIZER (USER_ID) VALUES (" & orgUserId & ")"
```

Both inserts run into the same table but try to create new independent rows. If USER_ID is primary key then your insert into ORG_NAME can't work that way.

You should learn more about SQL.

Comment: In my organization table , the (USER_ID) is a primary key as well as a foreign key. I modified the SQL command that inserts into the user_id and i worked. But when i added another command to insert the organization_name i ran into this problem.

Comment: you have to insert USER_ID and ORG_NAME in the same sql statement ... not in two independent scripts

Comment: Sorry it looks like access had some problems.
But your solution actually works.
Thanks man :)